# Sum of reciprocals vs. recirpocal of sum

Tags: inequality

How could one show that
$$
\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}?
$$
($x_i>0$ for all $i$ - if necessary one can even take $x_i>1$.)
It is quite easy to prove for $n=2$, but I am a bit lost with induction. Also, I suppose that this is a well-known result, but [using term *reciprocals* leads elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sums_of_reciprocals).

Comment: See [mean inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities).

Comment: [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Arithmetic_Mean_is_Never_Less_than_Harmonic_Mean) is the proof for the relevant inequality.